# Is it safe to use pthread_getname_np() to check if a thread is currently running?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have previously seen in a company's codebase (that developed embedded software for a linux based system using C) the use of `pthread_getname_np()` to check if a thread is currently running. I have also seen a couple of sources (like https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54766/pthread-getname-np-3c.html or https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/pthread_getname_np.3.asp) that declare that `pthread_getname_np()` returns `ESRCH` code error if the value specified by thread does not refer to an existing or running thread.

However having checked the numerous answers on how to check if a thread is currently running, I never saw anyone mentioning the use of `pthread_getname_np()` and therefore i have doubts if it is safe to use it to see if a thread is currenlty running or exited.

Comment: The first link is Solaris documentation, not Linux. The second is also not about Linux. The Linux (glibc) man page does not specify that `ESRCH` can be returned and looking at the implementation I don't think it can. This is not a standardized function.

Comment: I was thinking that they might had same behavior but for some reason linux man page omitted referring `ESRCH`.

Comment: The glibc implementation for linux is basically just reading `/proc/self/task/[tid]/comm` into the provided buffer and fails only if `open`/`read` fail or the buffer is too small.

Comment: So, can we suggest that `/proc/self/task/[tid]/comm` exists only if thread [tid] has not exited?

Comment: I don't know, but I would guess it to exist as long as the thread exists (either until termination for detached threads or until joined for non-detached threads + any time until the OS cleans up the kernel structures). However, thread ids can be reused, so I don't think this can be reliable (it could be a new thread after the one you are interested in has exited).

Comment: Note that even the Solaris docs you linked specify that `ESRCH` is raised if the specified thread ID does not refer to an *existing* thread. I would expect that to include joinable threads that have terminated but not yet been joined -- do you consider such to be "running"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to use pthread_getname_np() to check if a thread is currently running?

**No**.

Understand first that the `_np` in the function's name is mnemonic for "non-POSIX", and signifies that the function is a non-standard extension provided by your C library.  The behavior of functions of that name, where they exist, may differ between different libraries and different versions of those libraries, so **it is not safe to**

- rely on documentation of other pthreads implementations (Solaris, MKS, ...) to determine the expected behavior of your `pthread_getname_np()` calls.

Even limiting the scope of the question to Linux, there is more than one C standard library to consider, so **it is not safe to**

- assume that code depending on `pthread_getname_np()` and written and tested for one Linux environment will work correctly in all other Linux environments.

Moreover, the docs for Glibc's (and many others') `pthread_getname_np()` in no way specify that this function will fail if the designated thread has terminated.  Generally, they say that these functions are applicable to threads that *exist*. A thread exists for an arbitrary amount of time after terminating, until it is successfully joined (if it is joinable) or the system cleans it up (if it is detached).  So **it is not safe to**

- assume that success of a call to `pthread_getname_np()` implies that the thread identified by the specified thread ID is still running / runnable.

Furthermore, thread IDs can be reused, so in a context where new threads may be created throughout the lifetime of the application, and you're uncertain whether a given thread of interest still exists, **it is not safe to**

- assume that `pthread_getname_np()` will report on the thread you're actually interested in.